# Variable's value transfer from Jsp to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a dropdown of roles in JSP file. When a role is selected from the dropdown I want to get the selected role ID. When a role is selected then an `onchange` event occured and a function 'callAjax(roleId) is triggered. Here the roleId is jsp variable. I am trying to pass it through a javascript. But I can not able to do this. Is it really possible? Can any one help me to doing this. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<select name="role" onchange="callAjax(roleId)">
 <c:forEach items="${pro.roles}" var="rol" varStatus="status">
   <option value="${rol.id}">
    <c:out value="${rol.name}"/>
  </option>
 </c:forEach>               
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use the value which contains the id, so change to this:

```
 onchange="callAjax(this.value)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `onchange="callAjax(roleId)"` attribute from your `select`, and bind a change handler to the element with jQuery. The value returned by [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) will be the value from the selected `option`, which corresponds to the `rol.id` assigned to that option.

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='role']").change(function() {
        callAjax($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
onchange="callAjax('<%=roleId%>')"